# VMware gives error 'The processor does not support XSAVE' when trying to play VM

Tags: windows, vmware, hyper-v

When I try to play a VM on VMware I get this error:

```
The processor does not support XSAVE. This virtual machine cannot be powered on.
```

I saw some stuff online about disabling `hyper-v` in windows control panel, but when I look in `Control Panel -> Program and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off`, `hyper-v` is off.

I'm not sure what is wrong, because I previously used VMware on this computer and it worked. I uninstalled it, and now a few months later the same image won't run.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

Open command prompt as an administrator, `run bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`, and then reboot the computer.